# Logstash ruby filter conditional statement error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using the following filter to check if a field is null.

```
 filter {
   ruby{
      code => '
        userPref = {}
        user = {}
        group = {}
        groups = []

        if event.get("stripecustomerid") == "null" {
          group["groupName"] =  event.get("groupname");
          group["role"] =  event.get("type");
          groups << group;
       }
       '
     }
}
```

But when running, I get the following error,

```
SyntaxError: (ruby filter code):8: syntax error, unexpected tLCURLY
         if event.get("groupname") == "null" {
                                          ^
              eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1079
          register at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-ruby-3.0.2/lib/logstash/filters/ruby.rb:38
          register at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/forwardable.rb:201
   register_plugin at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:282
  register_plugins at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:293
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
  register_plugins at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:293
     start_workers at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:303
               run at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:232
    start_pipeline at /Users/Dummy/software/es/logstash-5.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:387
```

The event stream looks like this and I want to filter out "null" fields.

```
{"sqlId":1744,"minAllowance":{"hasSub":false,"subExpiry":0,"freeSec":1800,"freeSecExpiry":0},"groups":[{"groupName":null,"role":0}],"stripecustomerid":null
```

Any ideas on what can be going wrong?

Comment: Ruby doesn't use {} for blocks.  Remove both and replace the } with `end`

Comment: @Alcanzar Thanks for that - works now :)